# Conversion of data from php server to android failed

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

Is there an error in this part of coding? I don't understand where is the specific problem. As my result = null. After passing to the php and getting the php server reply. It didn't retrieve the data as it should. Debugging comes out no error, application is working but it just doesn't run as what I programmed it to do... Is there anyone can see any loop holes from this part?

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-    1"),8);

                sb = new StringBuilder();

                sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

                String line="0";

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result=sb.toString();
```

The PHP coding side

```
 $db_host = "localhost";
 $db_username = "root";
 $db_pass = "trickster911";
 $db_name = "track_database";

 @mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("Could not connect to database");
 @mysql_select_db("$db_name");


 $imei = $_POST['code3'];


 $sql=("SELECT latitude, longitude FROM track WHERE imei = ('$imei')") or die (mysql_error());
 $result=mysql_query($sql);


 if($result){
 echo "Y";
 }

 else {
 echo "N";
 }
 $output = array();
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))    
  $output[]=$row;
   print(json_encode($output));
   mysql_close();

 ?>
```

After debugging,

```
 JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal() line: 112  
 JSONTokener.nextValue() line: 90   
 JSONObject.<init>(JSONTokener) line: 154   
 JSONObject.<init>(String) line: 171    
 Tracking$1.onClick(View) line: 119 
 Button(View).performClick() line: 2408 
 View$PerformClick.run() line: 8816 
 ViewRoot(Handler).handleCallback(Message) line: 587    
 ViewRoot(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92    
 Looper.loop() line: 123    
 ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4627   
 Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not      available [native method]    
 Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521 
 ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 868 
 ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 626    
 NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Comment: `result` is definitely *not* null. `StringBuilder.toString()` *never* returns null. Beyond that, we don't have enough information to answer fully - we don't know what encoding the PHP server is using, for example. There definitely shouldn't be all those spaces in the encoding name though...

Comment: I set the result = null at first. Then I expect that after the data been receive from the server it will automatic override it... But it does. So I suspect this is the part of error.

Comment: Well if you're only seeing `result` as null, then you're never getting to the last line of code. But we can't walk you through the whole diagnostics process line by line, I'm afraid. Have you used a debugger? How far does it get? Does it *ever* read a line?

Comment: I debugged and it give me 1 error which tell me that result is unreadable. If I run the application it will only give out the value of result = null not the data that get from the php server side.

Comment: Just as before, you need to be **much** clearer in your communication when it comes to your debugging. You won't be able to use `result` until you assign it a value - but you should be able to step through before that. I'm afraid we're not going to be able to help you without more careful debugging (and reporting) than you've shown so far. I suggest you take a bit of time, debug carefully (ideally having created a short but *complete* Java console application - I suspect Android is irrelevant here), report *exactly* what happened, and edit all of this into your question.

Comment: Ok. I'm using eclipse for developing this application. I just copy & paste the debugged report then.

Comment: Tracking$1.onClick(View) line: 119     
Only this error i able to identify from my coding. Others I got no idea what error they are referring.

Comment: No, that's not what I suggested you do. That doesn't help us at all - it's just a single stack trace, without giving us any context. I suggest you read some introductory tutorials on effective debugging - without that, we're really not going to be able to help you.

Comment: Is there any example of how to show a more understanding context? I don't know how I to show u all my problem in whole.

Comment: Again, I've suggested that you write a short but complete console app - it doesn't need to be anything to do with Android - which *just* makes the post and fetches the data. That way we can see *all* your code, and you'll be in a better position to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
$sql=("SELECT latitude, longitude FROM track WHERE imei = ('$imei')") or die (mysql_error());
```

try this:

```
$sql=("SELECT latitude, longitude FROM track WHERE imei = '".$imei."'") or die (mysql_error());
```

I'm not sure but maybe your problem is because of this. Please give some feedback if it fixes your problem or not.

Comment: It became worst. The PHP pop up there is syntax error after changing into your suggestion. Anyway TQ.

Comment: You make an echo also print in JSON format inside PHP. I recommend you try to send and receive echo and print values in different times. You can see easier if there is a confusion while receiving both values.